# Animating backgroundPosition works poorly on IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, background-position

I tried to make jquery animate on the position of DIV image-background.
I use the http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html to do this effect.
The animation slide on the x axis, with this positions:

1. 0
2. 50
3. 80
4. 110
5. 70
6. 50

Its work fine, but on IE8 in all step its first of all go to x-position 0 and after that go to the right position.
For example in step 4, its start on 0 and make slide animation to 110.
Its wrong, because its should start on 80.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Why is the title of this question contain IE7 when the question surround IE8?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be mis-reading the start position of the element. Try setting the background-position on the CSS for the ".background" element, which is not currently defined.

Comment: This div have this css:
background: transparent url(../images/panorama.jpg) repeat-x center center

Comment: Use a separate background-position: property and express it in pixels. The script it probably trying to read this value.

Comment: this is my code:
<code>
$('#big_con').animate({'backgroundPosition': mar_left+' center'}, 1700, 'swing', function() {
 //some ajax code
});
</code>

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me:

```
(function($) {
if(!document.defaultView || !document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){ // IE6-IE8
    var oldCurCSS = $.curCSS;
    $.curCSS = function(elem, name, force){
        if(name === 'background-position'){
            name = 'backgroundPosition';
        }
        if(name !== 'backgroundPosition' || !elem.currentStyle || elem.currentStyle[ name ]){
            return oldCurCSS.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        var style = elem.style;
        if ( !force && style && style[ name ] ){
            return style[ name ];
        }
        return oldCurCSS(elem, 'backgroundPositionX', force) +' '+ oldCurCSS(elem, 'backgroundPositionY', force);
    };
}

var oldAnim = $.fn.animate;
$.fn.animate = function(prop){
    if('background-position' in prop){
        prop.backgroundPosition = prop['background-position'];
        delete prop['background-position'];
    }
    if('backgroundPosition' in prop){
        prop.backgroundPosition = '('+ prop.backgroundPosition;
    }
    return oldAnim.apply(this, arguments);
};

function toArray(strg){ strg = strg.replace(/left|top/g,'0px'); strg = strg.replace(/right|bottom/g,'100%'); strg = strg.replace(/center/g,'50%'); strg = strg.replace(/-\s/g,'-'); strg = strg.replace(/([0-9\.]+)(\s|\)|$)/g,"$1px$2"); var res = strg.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)\s(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)/); return [parseFloat(res[1],10),res[2],parseFloat(res[3],10),res[4]]; } 

$.fx.step. backgroundPosition = function(fx) {
    if (!fx.bgPosReady) {
        var start = $.curCSS(fx.elem,'backgroundPosition');
        if(!start){//FF2 no inline-style fallback
            start = '0px 0px';
        }

        start = toArray(start);
        fx.start = [start[0],start[2]];
        var end = toArray(fx.end);
        fx.end = [end[0],end[2]];

        fx.unit = [end[1],end[3]];
        fx.bgPosReady = true;
    }
    //return;
    var nowPosX = [];
    nowPosX[0] = ((fx.end[0] - fx.start[0]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[0] + fx.unit[0];
    nowPosX[1] = ((fx.end[1] - fx.start[1]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[1] + fx.unit[1];           
    fx.elem.style.backgroundPosition = nowPosX[0]+' '+nowPosX[1];

};
})(jQuery);


.
.
.
$('#big_con').animate({'backgroundPosition': mar_left+' center'}, 1700, 'swing', function() {
    //some ajax code.
});
```